# how default assignment operator works with string pointer

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

Should the code fail during runtime? Visual studio executes it without failure

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Boy
{
    string* _name;
public:
    Boy(string n) :_name(new string(n)) {}
    string getName() const { return *_name; }
};
int main() {
    Boy t("Tom");
    string str = "Tom2";
    t = str;
    cout << t.getName();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a `string` pointer there? What's the purpose / use case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the explicit keyword mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-mean)

Comment: @alex That would be better, but doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should the code fail during runtime?

No, it shouldn't.

Let's dissect, what the following line does:

```
t = str;
```

There's a temporary `Boy` instance implicitely constructed. Thus it's merely the same as

```
t = Boy(str);
```

the `operator=` copies the pointer generated in the constructor to `t._name`.
The temporarily created `Boy` instance goes away, without deleting the internally managed pointer (as it should).

Thus your code works without failure or undefined behavior (but leaks memory).

---

Said all that above, what you really should do, is the following class declaration:

```
class Boy {
    std::string name;
public:
    Boy(const std::string& n) : name(n) {}
    const std::string& getName() const { return name; }
};
```

and stop worrying about pointers, memory management and all of that stuff, YAGNI. `std::string`, and other container classes provided by the c++ standard library are designed to do all of that for you in an efficient, safe, and less error prone manner.

Comment: at the end the temporal object and t both are deleted. but the both point same string pointer?

Comment: @Yakov I don't fully understand your question, but I suspect, that you believe, that the memory held by the`_name` pointer would be automatically deleted, when an instance of `Bob` is destroeyed. But that's not the case, you would need to call `delete _name;` explicitely in the destructor to do so.

Comment: @Yakov Is your main programming background C#?

Comment: @Yakov Note that the constructor of `Boy` takes it's argument `n` by value - it makes an independent copy whenever you call it. Then it copies it again in `_name(new string(n))`. On that note: A pointer to a standard container is almost never what you want.